# Cómo dar formato de Hipervínculo a cada una de las URLS indicadas en una celda, separadas por comas y sin espacios (URL1,URL2,URL3...)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una hoja de cálculo donde en la columna 1 se indican en cada celda URLS separadas por comas, pero no están hipervinculadas, por lo que no puedo acceder a ellas salvo que les asigne manualmente su vínculo => (url1,url2,url3...)

El código de ejemplo está programado para que se aplique a la celda activa. Primero extrae la primera url de la celda, con `substring(0, indexes[0])` y la formatea con un `sh.getRange("D1").setRichTextValue(RichTextValue);` colocándolo en la celda D1 con su hipervinculo correspondiente. Para el resto de urls, a partir de la segunda,  con un `for(var...)` extraigo cada url con `myLinks.substring(indexes[j]+1, indexes[j+1])` y a continuación intento aplicarle formato a cada url extraida. Aquí es donde tengo el problema. He añadido también un `setRichTextValue(RichTextValue)`, pero no se lo aplica. Algo estoy haciendo mal.
Resumiendo, necesito que una vez extraídas todas las urls, les pueda aplicar el formato de hipervínculo y  las coloque todas en la celda donde estaban
inicialmente sin vinculo.

```
function hiperLink(){

 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Hoja 
 activa

 var rng = sh.getActiveRange();

 var val = rng.getValue().toString();

var sCell = val.split(",");

var row = rng.getRowIndex();
var col = rng.getColumnIndex();

var indexes = [];
for(var i=0; i<val.length;i++){
if(val[i] === ',') indexes.push(i);
}
console.log('Mis urls: ' + val) // Datos por celda
console.log('Número de datos a separar: ' + sCell.length); // Muestra el 
número de datos separados por comas que tiene la celda
console.log('Número de caracteres: ' + val.length) // Cuenta el número de 
caracteres
console.log('indexes: ' + indexes.length); 

if( indexes.length == 0 ) { 
var url1 = val.substring(0, indexes[0]);
var url1Long = url1.length

console.log('url1: ' + url1);
console.log('longUrl1 ' + url1Long )
}

if( indexes.length > 0 ) {

for(var j =0; j < sCell.length; j++) {  

var urlM = val.substring(indexes[j-1]+1, indexes[j]);
var urlMLong = urlM.length
console.log('urlM: ' + urlM);
console.log('longUrlM ' + urlMLong )
 }
}
```

Comment: Ma parece que tienes algunos problemas de concepto en el manejo de variables en Google Apps Script / JavaScript. Declara la variable `RichTextValue`en dos lugares , uno antes del bucle y otra vez dentro del bucle. Con la declaración dentro del bucle el script no hace nada. Intenta corregir eso.

Comment: Muy mal lo llevo, la verdad. He editado el código. He podido separar las urls y calcular su longitud de caracteres para poder utilizarlas en los 'setRichTextValue' , fuera y dentro de los bucles. Pero no consigno nada con ello. No se cómo vincular cada url a su vinculo correspondiente y que se muestren en la celda activa. Si alguien sabe y puede ayudarme, se lo agradecería. Siento las molestias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la [respuesta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150147/88163) a [How do you dynamically add multiple URLs into rich text for Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150133/88163)

```
var fileList = ["www.file1.com", "www.file2.com", "www.file3.com"];
var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
var text = "";
var links = [];

for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) { // Sets the start of the link.
    var start = text.length;
  } else {
    var start = text.length + 2;
  }
  if (i == 0) { // Sets the file number.
    text = "File 1"
  } else {
    var num = i + 1;
    text = text + ", File " + num.toString();
  }
  var end = text.length; // Sets the end of the link.
  links.push([start, end, fileList[i]]);
}

richText.setText(text);
for (l = 0; l < links.length; l++) {
  richText.setLinkUrl(links[l][0],links[l][1],links[l][2])
}

richText = richText.build();
```

Nótese que el código anterior primero agrega los textos de cada enlace y luego a cada uno de estos les agrega el URL del enlace usando `setLinkUrl`

A continuación un ejemplo de cómo usar el código anterior

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {Array} URLs Array que incluye los URLs de los enlaces
 */
function myFunction(URLs){

  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
  var text = "";
  var links = [];

  for (i = 0; i < URLs.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) { // Inicio del enlace
      var start = text.length;
    } else {
      var start = text.length + 2;
    }
    if (i == 0) { // Establece el texto del enlace.
      text = "Enlace 1"
    } else {
      var num = i + 1;
      text = text + ", Enlace " + num.toString();
    }
    var end = text.length; // Sets the end of the link.
    links.push([start, end, URLs[i]]);
  }

  richText.setText(text);
  for (l = 0; l < links.length; l++) {
    richText.setLinkUrl(links[l][0],links[l][1],links[l][2])
  }

  return richText.build();

}
```

Comment: Funciona!!! Nada que ver con lo que yo estaba haciendo. Objetivo conseguido

Comment: @SalvaSolbes Por favor lee, [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)